# call method on dynamically added contents in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dynamic

I have a list that call ListReorder() method from [ListReorder Plugin](http://www.utdallas.edu/~jrb048000/ListReorder/) on that it's work correctly but when add an item to list dynamically and recall ListReorder function on that list don't work on dynamically added list items:

```
function DragDropList(){        

var lists = $('ul#list1').ListReorder();

lists.bind('listorderchanged', function(evt, jqList, listOrder) {
var str="";
        for (var i = 0; i < listOrder.length; i++)
        {
            str += "<div class='gadget'>" + Gadgets[listOrder[i]] + "\n</div>";
        }
        $("#Preview").contents().find(".sidebar").html(str);
});
}



 //add Gadget

$("#addGadgetBtn").live('click',function()
    {
        //add new list item here
        DragDropList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to use

```
lists.live();
```

instead of

```
lists.bind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a change in the plugin and expose its `resetList()` method.

Change

```
function resetList() {
```

to

```
this.resetList = function() {
```

and then after you insert the new elements in the list run `$('ul#list1').resetList()`

Comment: get error because on internal calling cannot find resetList method

Comment: @malaria Move the definition above the call.. or use this.resetList